# Desktop configuration file cannot launch Android Studio

Tags: command-line, launcher, android-studio

I did not want to launch Android Studio from terminal, so I wrote the following `android-studio.desktop` file

```
 [Desktop Entry]
 Version=1.0
 Type=Application
 Name=Android Studio
 Exec=sh /home/ashraf/tools/android/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
 Icon=/home/ashraf/tools/android/android-studio/bin/studio.png
 Categories=Development;IDE;
 Terminal=false
```

and saved it in Desktop. I permitted this file to be executed as a program. After all that done, double-clicking the Android Studio icon is not launching the IDE. But when I run `sh /home/ashraf/tools/android/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` from terminal, it launches. Help me out. I would like to fix this file only, no other solution.

Comment: Possibly, you need to *be* in the `studio.sh` 's directory first. When you run it from the terminal, are you in `/home/ashraf/tools/android/android-studio/bin`? (I asked you before, but got no reply :) )

Comment: I just run the terminal and run `sh /home/ashraf/tools/android/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`. I don't have to go to the `bin` directory. By the way, I did not get your question.

Comment: I was in the GNOME DE. I came back to the old Unity DE and the default launcher created by the android studio installation worked. So, I think GNOME caught the problem hard.

Comment: Try replacing `sh` with `bash` in the `Exec=` field. Also, try making the script executable (`chmod +x /home/ashraf/tools/android/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`)